# Exception "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed"

Tags: asp.net

The stack trace of the error is as shown

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SystemException: The trust relationship between the primary domain
>   and the trusted domain failed. ]
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) +1185
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed) +44
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) +47
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +101 
>   System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsTheUserInAnyRole(StringCollection
>   roles, IPrincipal principal) +123
>   System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal
>   user, String verb) +256
>   System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRuleCollection.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal
>   user, String verb) +199
>   System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.OnEnter(Object source,
>   EventArgs eventArgs) +8872580
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: Put your code or some detail explanation here.

Comment: This isn't ASP.NET related. This says that you run your web site on one domain and try to authenticate against another that *doesn't* trust yours anymore. What is your *topology*? Do you run on a DMZ?  Is the trust relation between the domains valid? Did the trust relationship work in the past or is this the first time you tried it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it was happening when I am running my ASP.net application. In my detailed analysis I found this might be related to Authentication and Authorization set in web config file. In my we config it was written it uses windows authentication and in authorization tag  it has deny tag also. And it some what worked and issue resolved when I did Allow all (*) in the authorization tag in web config,, thank you for your effort.

Comment: @RinoyMA the defaults are OK, you don't need to change them. What you did didn't solve anything. It **DISABLED  authorization COMPLETELY**. You *HAVE* to have a deny all, in order to add individual allows!!!! You *still* have a domain problem, but you no longer check whether the user is allowed to access your site or not

Comment: @RinoyMA in other words, congrats, you got pwned.

Comment: You need to read how security works in ASP.NET. This is part of most tutorials and courses, especially those found in http://asp.net and Microsoft's Virtual Accademy.

Comment: Ok I have to read it in detail. For time being for entering into the application I will use "allow all" for entering in to the application and I know it is not the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually root cause for the above issue was in my web.config file we had Authentication(windows) and Authorization entries which was restricting my login into the system. Then I corrected the config file so that I can log in to the system by allowing everybody to login. My config is now look like

```
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>       <authorization>       <allow users="*"/>        
 </authorization>
```